# redirection and routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently reading Beginning Rails 3.  I have a question about redirection.  The book states that "redirect_to can also take an object as a parameter" vs a path.  So the example they give is that

```
redirect_to(@article)
```

is a shortcut equivalent to

```
redirect_to(article_path(:id => @article))
```

I'm not sure I understand this.  What exactly is the line :id => @article saying?

thanks,
mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect_to(@article)` is a shortcut for
`redirect_to(article_path(@article))`.  Rails can do this because it extracts the class name from the `@article` variable, something like `send("#{@article.class.name.downcase}_path")`.

`redirect_to(article_path(@article))` is a shortcut for `redirect_to(article_path(:id => @article))`, which is a shortcut for `redirect_to(article_path(:id => @article.to_param))`.  Basically Rails says, @article is an ActiveRecord object, I'll ask it for it's magical `to_param` value.  By default, `to_param` just returns the article's ID, but you can overwrite this to return like a slug or nicename, like `38-hello-world`.

So `redirect_to(@article)` is really saying, OK, I have an Article, so I need the path to the articles, and I need the resource identifier, or `to_param`, of the article.

Then it constructs the URL!

Answer (score 0):

`:id => @article` is a shortcut for `:id => @article.to_param`, which just specifies *which* article you're looking to view.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, execute `rake routes` in your console. It will display the list of your app's routes.
There will be a route called *article*.

`article_path` is simply the link for the route *article*.

And by doing `(:id => @article)`, you're passing it an `id` parameter that has the `@article` value.